Iterated Eigenvector Computation for 2x2 Matrices
Choose a "random" $2\times 2$ matrix $U_0$. For example choose each entry as iid complex Gaussians. Now run $U_1={\tt Eigenvectors}[U_0]$, where ${\tt Eigenvectors}$ is Mathematica's algorithm for computing the eigenvectors of a matrix. Similarly run $U_2={\tt Eigenvectors}[U_1]$, and likewise compute $U_3,U_4,\cdots$. Surprisingly, this process seems to always generate a sequence $U_0,U_1,\cdots$ that converges to the identity matrix! I'm trying to understand why.
This question is not so much about Mathematica, except for some choices Mathematica makes when computing eigenvectors. After all, except in degenerate cases eigenvectors are determined up to scaling. But it turns out that not all choices of scaling lead to the same convergence. For some reason Mathematica's choices do, however.
In more detail, Mathematica's ${\tt Eigenvectors}[U_i]$ outputs a matrix $U_{i+1}$ whose rows are the eigenvectors of $U_i$. What seems to be important for convergence is that $U_{i+1}$ is chosen so that (1) each row/eigenvector is a unit vector, and (2) moreover at least one entry in each row/eigenvector is real. Remember that the eigenvectors can always be scaled by an arbitrary complex scalar, so we can always assume a unit eigenvector, and by multiplying by an appropriate phase $e^{i\theta}$ we can always take at least one of the entries in each eigenvector to be real.
I'm not sure exactly how Mathematica chooses which entry to be real. However, it seems to have a preference for choosing the entries $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ in $U_i$ to be real. If I override Mathematica's eigenvector computation and force $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ to be real, I get the same convergence. Interestingly, however, if I force entries $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ to be real, then the sequence actually does not seem to converge, though the norm of each entry converges to $1/\sqrt{2}$. If I choose entries $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$ to be real, I get no convergence at all. I apply random phases to each eigenvector, there is also no convergence.
Can anyone explain this phenomenon? Why should choosing the off-diagonal entries in an eigenvector computation to be real cause the sequence to converge? Why should choosing the on-diagonal entries to be real cause the sequence to partially converge?
As a bonus question, I couldn't replicate anything similar for 3x3 unitary matrices. Is there a way to choose phases to cause the $3\times 3$ (or higher-dimensional) cases to converge? Or is there something special about the $2\times 2$ case?

Can you clarify your procedure a bit more? If I understand correctly, it seems that at each step you take the conjugate transpose of the matrix (equal to setting eigenvectors as rows), possibly to then transform its columns. These operations do not seem to change much. Also, these transformations seem to be equivalently applied either column-wise or row-wise, but still, I don't see clearly what the change is. In other words, I'm having difficulty reproducing your steps.

I compute the eigenvectors of the matrix, and assemble them as rows in a new matrix. This is not the same as taking the conjugate transpose. Namely, we can write $U_0$ as $VDV^\dagger$ where $V$ is a unitary matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Then I output $U_1=V^T$. The transpose on V is un-necessary, and the same phenomenon will occur if I just set $U_1=V$.
